# Nativescript - groceries sample throws Unknown compiler option 'sourcemaps'

Tags: nativescript

Nativescript - groceries sample throws Unknown compiler option 'sourcemaps'

While building it for android.

Deleted the node_modules forlder and reinstalled the android platform

Result was no effect at all..

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have `sourcemaps` in your tsconfig.json 
that it's not allowed.
Your tsconfig should be like this:

for NS_Angular2:

https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries/blob/angular-start/tsconfig.json

and for NS:

https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries/blob/master/tsconfig.json